# ITMS-90896 Error when uploading binary to AppStore with Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build, app-store

I'm facing this error while uploading build to the AppStore

> Invalid Mach-O header. The __swift5_entry section is missing for
> extension bundle Payload/***********WidgetExtension.appex, which
> prevents the extension from running. You can run the otool command
> against your binary to ensure there is a __swift5_entry section. With
> error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90896 for id
> 9a015ff9-02cd-4ba6-9305-5d5a7b89540b

For information the app is using Swift 5, Xcode 13.3.1, deployment target iOS 13.0 
I have two widgets (extensions) in the app, one for iOS 13 and one for iOS 14.1 
Any leads for fixing this please?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those who have this issue, we finally succeeded to fix this issue, by deleting the widget and re-created it with the newest Xcode. 
 Like this the build was accepted when submitted to the AppStore

Answer (score 0):

In our case, it related to the Live Activities. We have `test` and `production` targets - one of the files was only in `test` target, while it should have been in both `test` and `production` targets.